# Xamarin Android Xamarin.Essentials GeoCoding pantalla en Negro

Tags: xamarin.android

Segun la documentación de Microsoft esta función esta correcta, pero al ejecutarla(mandando los parámetros) correctos se queda estancado en la primera linea.

```cs
async Task<string> getAddress(double lat, double lng)
        {

            var placemarks = await Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(lat, lng);

            var placemark = placemarks?.FirstOrDefault();
            if (placemark != null)
            {
                string geocodeAddress =
                    $"AdminArea:       {placemark.AdminArea}\n" +
                    $"CountryCode:     {placemark.CountryCode}\n" +
                    $"CountryName:     {placemark.CountryName}\n" +
                    $"FeatureName:     {placemark.FeatureName}\n" +
                    $"Locality:        {placemark.Locality}\n" +
                    $"PostalCode:      {placemark.PostalCode}\n" +
                    $"SubAdminArea:    {placemark.SubAdminArea}\n" +
                    $"SubLocality:     {placemark.SubLocality}\n" +
                    $"SubThoroughfare: {placemark.SubThoroughfare}\n" +
                    $"Thoroughfare:    {placemark.Thoroughfare}\n";

                return geocodeAddress;
            }
            return null;
        }
```